# Import errors are showing after installing Ansible on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine

Tags: ansible

I am getting the below mentioned import error after installing ansible on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/sourav/ansible/bin/ansible", line 62, in <module>
         import ansible.constants as C
     File "/home/sourav/ansible/lib/ansible/constants.py", line 12, in <module>
     from jinja2 import Template
         ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

Comment: You installed it, fine, but **how**? Via `pip`, via `apt` via the sources, ... ?

Answer (score 1):

There is the root cause for that error message:

> ImportError: No module named jinja2

Hence, if you installed Ansible via `pip`, try running:

```
sudo pip3 install Jinja2
```

Or if you installed it via `apt`, run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-jinja2
```

Comment: I had installed it via pip. The issue was resolved after giving a restart to the VM. Thanks for suggesting the way outs.